# Parse.com: Sending email to admin after new user signup

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as the backend for my iOS application.

When a new user signs up in my app and Parse creates a new user in the "User" table, I would like to get notified by email (in order to validate the user data and activate some premium features manually).

Is sending an email from Parse.com after user signup possible?

How could I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this by using one of the mail [Cloud Modules](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide) from an afterSave hook on the User class: `Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) { ... if user just signed up, email them ... });`